# Why this cannot be used in the main method of a Java class?

Tags: java

I have used Java for about six months but I am somewhat at a loss as to exactly how the `this` statement works. I know that it is used to refer to an calling instance. But why does it not need to be used in the main method to reference the object that is created in the main method?

I think that the this is always referring to the current object that has priority over the other objects. In the constructor the this is for the new object being created, correct. In the main method the this.x.method is referring to the object that is in the main statement.

Question: The **this** keyword refers to the current object that is being created? or does it refer to the object that is being made into a new object?

class:

```
public class DDHThisTest {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public DDHThisTest(int a, int b) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DDHThisTest i = new DDHThisTest();
        this.i.x = 10;

    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot use this in a static context

Comment: As error message says, you cannot use `this` in static method. Just `i.x` should work.

Comment: `this` is a speical variable which is automatically supplied to all *instances* of a class.  `static` methods have no instance, thus they can not reference `this`....You might [Using the `this` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) of some use...

Comment: i **is not** a member field, it's just a variable in a local scope. And main is a static method which do not reference a context object (not concerning how static is implemented under the hood).

Comment: can someone comment on *why* `main` is `static`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

main method is a static method.
keyword `this` is to be used in object/instance scope not in a static block.

Simply replace `this.i.x = 10;` with `i.x = 10;` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `this.i.x` since you cannot refer to instance variables inside a `static` method, in this case `main()`. To solve this just remove the `this` before `i.x`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DDHThisTest i = new DDHThisTest(1, 2);
    i.x = 10;
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to pass arguments to the constructor while creating an instance of `DDHThisTest`, because you have not declared a constructor without parameters.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in a `static` block, you have no object scope.  That means that there is not a particular instance of the class you are working with, so there is no reference to "this instance of the class".

Answer (score 2):

Main is a static method and it is called before the object of DDHThisTest class is made. So ypu are trying ro refer to an instance of a class which is yet to be instantiated.  So you are getting the error. In other words you know that only static variables can be accessed from static methods.  But 'this' is an instance variable so to say; because of which you can't access it from static method.

Answer (score 1):

```
i.x = 10;
```

In static function, there is NO `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword "this" is reserved to be used as part of an instance.
If you remove the "this.", you should be fine.