# why "this" keyword is not allowed in main method in java

Tags: java, static, this

Why this keyword cannot be used in static method.

```
   class Hello{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(this); 
    }
   }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to represent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method

Comment: Duplicate. Search before ask

Comment: i have searched but unfortunately unable to find the proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main method is static and therefore cannot be accessed with the keyword `this` :)

Note: Indeed, the question has been answered already : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225474/why-this-cannot-be-used-in-the-main-method-of-a-java-class)

Comment: In more gentle words: when you have another questions which also answers the current one, then flag it as a duplicate instead of writing the same stuff as an answer.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for pointing that out. Nobody here is farming reputation, but more like helping people. I didn't even know how to flag for duplicate until you mentioned that.

Comment: *"Nobody here is farming reputation"* A lot of people do (sadly). When you're not one of them, then that is really nice to hear. Help page about flagging: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Mine is grown organically.

Comment: The person is not `accessing` the main method with the `this` keyword. It would mean doing this: `this.main();`. What the OP does is absolutely nonsensical. He's trying to display the value of a (final) object, which is impossible.